# How can I remove specific members from the list in python?

Tags: python, list

this is my code, I want to know where the problem is with this code
And also, instead of removing and, no, i from the list; replace it with a number.

```
word = input("your sentece in english : ")
Word = word.split()
Word = word.lower()
new_word = ""
delet = ["and","no","i"]
print(Word)
for m in Word:
    if m not in delet:
        new_word = new_word + m
print(new_word)
```

Comment: use else condition when m in the delet

Comment: `Word = word.lower()` sets `Word` to a string, not a list. Use `Word = word.lower().split()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `enumerate`,

`for index, m in enumerate(Word): if m in delet: Word[index] = int`